# Looking for an example of fb:tabs and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, fbjs

I want to use http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:tabs and have the tabs load/change dynamically using AJAX. Are there any examples online or would anyone be kind enough to post an example here?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can make your own tabs simple html&js